# Sed is not replacing the values in a file

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

Have a file with the following data in it:

samplefile:

```
id|mdl_name|mdl_tagid|mdl_brnchcd|mdls_mktvl
NoData|\N|6ypXQwLw8H9svA|04271|NoData
NoData|\N|7MFzlQriUjohVg|60475|NoData
NoData|\N|8AtEVeaU3fiK5w|91305|NULL
NoData|\N|AA3B5BNqNTokWw|87818|NoData
NoData|\N|CG79LhAgIeBkPw|80199|NULL
```

Using `sed` to replace the `NoData`,`NULL` and `\N`:

```
    sed -i "s/\\\\\N//g" samplefile
    sed -i "s/\x0//g" samplefile
    sed -i "s/NoData//g" samplefile
```

Actual result:

```
id|mdl_name|mdl_tagid|mdl_brnchcd|mdls_mktvl
NoData|\N|6ypXQwLw8H9svA|04271|NoData
NoData|\N|7MFzlQriUjohVg|60475|NoData
NoData|\N|8AtEVeaU3fiK5w|91305|NULL
NoData|\N|AA3B5BNqNTokWw|87818|NoData
NoData|\N|CG79LhAgIeBkPw|80199|NULL
```

Expected Result:

```
id|mdl_name|mdl_tagid|mdl_brnchcd|mdls_mktvl
||6ypXQwLw8H9svA|04271|
||7MFzlQriUjohVg|60475|
||8AtEVeaU3fiK5w|91305|
||AA3B5BNqNTokWw|87818|
||CG79LhAgIeBkPw|80199|
```

Not getting what's wrong or missing in the `sed` command that it's not producing the desired result.

Updating with the test results after implementing the suggestions:

1. Suggestion_1:

   `sed -Ei 's/\\N|NULL|NoData//g'  samplefile`

   ```
   id|mdl_name|mdl_tagid|mdl_brnchcd|mdls_mktvl
   6ypXQwLw8H9svA|04271
   7MFzlQriUjohVg|60475
   8AtEVeaU3fiK5w|91305
   AA3B5BNqNTokWw|87818
   CG79LhAgIeBkPw|80199
   ```
2. Suggestion_2:

   `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR>1{$1=$2=$5=""} 1' samplefile`

   ```
   id|mdl_name|mdl_tagid|mdl_brnchcd|mdls_mktvl
   6ypXQwLw8H9svA|04271
   7MFzlQriUjohVg|60475
   8AtEVeaU3fiK5w|91305
   AA3B5BNqNTokWw|87818
   CG79LhAgIeBkPw|80199
   ```

Still, it's not matching the Expected result. Is there a way to retain the delimiters and replace the values with just a space?

Comment: `NoData` != `NoValue` and `\x0` != `NULL`

Comment: also use singlequotes if you don't need shell substitutions on the content. `sed -Ei 's/\\N|NULL|NoData//g' thefile`

Comment: Why not just delete the contents of the 1st, 2nd, and 5th fields with `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR>1{$1=$2=$5=""} 1' file`?

Comment: I've tested it and it does work. (except it leaves `NULL`s in the file) Check if you didn't make a typo in the file name.

Comment: The awk version, at least, gives the expected results on your sample input file.

Comment: `sed -Ei 's/\\N|NULL|NoData//g'  samplefile` does leave the delimiters in the file. What version of `sed` do you use? (the first line of `sed --version`)

Comment: your `sed` seems to be buggy if it captures the pipe symbol as well.  What version are you using? (`try sed --version`)

Comment: all the code listed in the question works for me; in addition to the output from `sed --version` I'd also want to see the output from `awk --version` and `od -c samplefile` (to see if there are any non-printing/control characters in the mix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing your code  `Suggestion_2` from  @EdMorton comment,  in GNU `awk` gets the `expected result`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR>1{$1=$2=$5=""} 1' file                                     id|mdl_name|mdl_tagid|mdl_brnchcd|mdls_mktvl
||6ypXQwLw8H9svA|04271|
||7MFzlQriUjohVg|60475|
||8AtEVeaU3fiK5w|91305|
||AA3B5BNqNTokWw|87818|
||CG79LhAgIeBkPw|80199|
```

GNU awk version:

```
awk --version
GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
....
```

and same result with the `sed` from @jthill comment:

```
sed  -E 's/(\\N|NULL|NoData)//g' file         id|mdl_name|mdl_tagid|mdl_brnchcd|mdls_mktvl
||6ypXQwLw8H9svA|04271|
||7MFzlQriUjohVg|60475|
||8AtEVeaU3fiK5w|91305|
||AA3B5BNqNTokWw|87818|
||CG79LhAgIeBkPw|80199|
```

This can help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145402/regex-alternation-or-operator-foobar-in-gnu-or-bsd-sed